# How can I find documents in a collection based on array values

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I tried adding a helper to return array with documents, which looks like:

```
documents = {
  realPlayers: [],
  subscribers: [
                {playerId: }, 
                {playerId: }, 
                {playerId: }
               ],
  privatGame:,
  gameType:,
  gameStatus: 'active'
}
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work (forEach too):

```
Template.myGames.helpers({
    'myGames': function() {
        let gamePul = [],
            activeGames = Games.find({gameStatus: "active"});
            for (var i = 0; i < activeGame.length; i++) {
              if (activeGame[i].subscribers) {
                for (var j = 0; j < activeGame[i].subscribers.length; j++) {
                  if (activeGame[i].subscribers[j].playerId = Meteor.userId()) gamePul.push(activeGame[i]);
                }
              }
            };
            return gamePul;
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you get back for `activeGames`? Should be a cursor that you can use `.forEach` on. Do you get any results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just trying to find the set of games the current user is a subscriber to right? You just need `$elemMatch` in your query:

```
Template.myGames.helpers({
  myGames: function() {
    return Games.find({ gameStatus: "active",
      subscribers: { $elemMatch: { playerId: Meteor.userId() }}});
  }
});
```

[docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

Comment: yes, u completely right n it's completely working! thanks!)